# When, precisely, is the stock supposed to be reduced?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WordPress site with a custom template that was not originally made with e-commerce in mind. Now we've added WooCommerce, and, while most stuff is working fine, there's one specific thing that I'm not able to figure out.

We've enabled inventory management under WooCommerce Settings, and individually on some products as well.

But when a product with Stock management enabled is added to a basket, the inventory is not reduced. Not even when the order is completed - the stock is never updated.

Why could this be?

Comment: stock is reduced precisely on actions: 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold'

Comment: to be more precise the first action executed of the previously mentioned four actions does the stock reduction. actions executed later are ignored so there is no duplicate stock reduction. my experience is that the action 'woocommerce_payment_complete' will be the first called. Incidentally, for payment by check this is when the customer indicates he will send you a check not when the check is received. this always works on my system so I think you have a problem somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, @user9372991. I'll  see if I can figure out what goes wrong.

Comment: If WooCommerce tries to reduce stock either the order note 'Stock levels reduced:' or the order note 'Unable to reduce stock for item' or their translations should be generated and be visible on the admin order page in the left column. If these order notes do not exists then none of the four actions was actually done. Otherwise, you should get the order note 'Unable to reduce stock for item' for failures.

Comment: Also, can you verify in the options data base that the option_value of option_name 'woocommerce_manage_stock' is 'yes' and in the postmeta database the meta_value of the meta_key '_manage_stock' is 'yes' for the product. If these things are not true then the reduce stock action will not be done. As far as I can see this is the only reason reduce stock action will not be done.

Comment: Thanks again - will look at the issue over the weekend